# How much correlation is significant enough to build a regression model?

Tags: r, regression, time-series

I am trying to build a regression model using two time series data in R. There is not much correlation between the two time series, so I am using trend part of both time series(using STL decomposition) for the model. The maximum correlation between these two is about 0.6 at a fixed lag. Is this sufficient to establish that one time series affects the other and build a regression model upon them.

Comment: as climate scientists have shown us there's no need to correlate too much to make grand conclusions :)

Answer (score 0):

"The maximum correlation between these two is about 0.6 at a fixed lag. Is this sufficient to establish that one time series affects the other" Correlation does not imply causation. Just because to sets of data are correlated it does not mean one affects the other. You could take a look at the [Granger Causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality) test. This might be more aligned with what you want to do

Comment: Apologies for mixing up my words. Your answer hopefully helps; wasn't aware of this test before.

Comment: while looking up the test you mentioned, i came up against another test called convergent cross mapping. It would be very helpful if you could explain the significance of this test too. Thanks in advance